# Understanding list comprehension vs traditional loop and build

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to nail my understanding and best use of Lists, I have come across list comprehension and read plenty about them, but am choking on one particular burning question.

Given this challenge:

```
def matrix_mult(m1, m2):
    """
      >>> matrix_mult([[1, 2], [3,  4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]])
      [[19, 22], [43, 50]]
      >>> matrix_mult([[1, 2, 3], [4,  5, 6]], [[7, 8], [9, 1], [2, 3]])
      [[31, 19], [85, 55]]
      >>> matrix_mult([[7, 8], [9, 1], [2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
      [[39, 54, 69], [13, 23, 33], [14, 19, 24]]
    """
```

I created this solution, to me it seemed most logical and matched my previous programming experience, I more or less typed as i was thinking ...

```
# 1 using a traditional List buildup method    
res = []
for i in range(len(m1)):
    sub = []
    for j in range(len(m2[0])):
        sub.append(row_times_column( m1, i, m2, j ))
    res.append(sub)
return res
```

Then I found this solution which featured 'list comprehension' (I renamed the vars to match mine in order to better grok the diffs between the two solutions:

```
# 2 using list comprehension
res = [[0] * len(m1) for x in xrange(len(m2[0]))]
for i in range(len(res)):
   for j in range(len(res[i])):
       res[i][j] = row_times_column(m1, i, m2, j)
return res
```

The second solution is building a zero based matrix which matches the shape of the intended answer, **but is this method what is meant by "list comprehension"**, or is there more going on here?

Here is the row_times_column() def, for fullness.

```
def row_times_column(m1, row, m2, column):
    """
      >>> row_times_column([[1, 2], [3, 4]], 0, [[5, 6], [7, 8]], 0)
      19
      >>> row_times_column([[1, 2], [3, 4]], 0, [[5, 6], [7, 8]], 1)
      22
    """
    i = 0
    for index, value in enumerate(m1[row]):
       i += value * m2[index][column]
    return i
```

I suspect there is a third (and many more) way of solving this, using a lambda, but I thought I'd ask for comment on these 2 first.

Example taken from http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch09.html

**EDIT**
Got a much better handle on list comprehension now, thx to answers here given.

Still, can anyone explain the logic of creating a blank matrix into which the correct answers are placed vs just creating a new list?

Comment: If you don't create a blank matrix before, the `res[i][j] =` syntax gives an error because the item doesn't exist; so you have to use `res.append()` which doesn't read as nicely as the syntax here. I think that's the only reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

List comprehension is simply a way of creating a list based on another list. (Or other iterable item)

For instance, if we have a list `a = [1, 2, 5, 7]`, then we could create a list, `b`, containing the values of `a` doubled in two ways.

#### Without list comprehensions

```
b = []
for e in a:
    b.append(2*e)
```

#### With list comprehensions

```
b = [2*e for e in a]
```

There's nothing more to it than that. It's simply a nice syntax for building lists based on lists.

#### See also:

- [Python: List Comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)
- [List Comprehensions on (An Unofficial) Python Tutorial Wiki](http://pytut.infogami.com/intermediate_listcomps)

Answer (score 3):

The first line is a list comprehension. The rest is not.

```
 return [[row_times_column(m1, i, m2, j) for j in range(len(res[i]))]
     for i in range(len(res))]
```

Answer (score 3):

The following also uses list comprehension for matrix multiplication

```
def matrix_mult(m1, m2):
  return [[sum(m1[i][k]*m2[k][j] for k in range(len(m2))) for j in range(len(m2[0]))] for i in range(len(m1))]
```

Comment: Thx Howard, I suspected such a thing must exist but could not imagine how it would look! Gonna have to break that down...

Answer (score 1):

The rationale between list comprehension in Python is explained in [PEP 202](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)

> List comprehensions provide a more concise way to create lists in situations where map() and filter() and/or nested loops would currently be used.

So there is really no "special trickery" behind the idea. It's just a *syntactical extension*, to put it as the PEP does.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Mark Pilgrim does a much better job at explaining list comprehension than I could in his book [Dive into Python](http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/mapping_lists.html). This book is really good for starting out in Python and just a good read in general. Recommended.

P.S.: There's list comprehension for Python 3 as well in [Dive into Python 3](http://diveintopython3.net/comprehensions.html#listcomprehension)